# Pyspark dataframe get a list of columns where at least one row meets a condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a PySpark `DataFrame`

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
0.1  0.2  0.3
```

I want to get the column names where at least one row meets a condition for example a row is bigger than 0.1

My expected result is should be in this case:

```
[Co2 , Co3]
```

I cannot provide any code because truly I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `count` items satisfying the predicate (internal `select`) and process the results:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, when

[c for c, v in df.select([
    count(when(col(c) > 0.1, 1)).alias(c) for c in df.columns
]).first().asDict().items() if v]
```

Step by step:

- Aggregate (`DataFrame` -> `DatFrame`):

  ```
  df = sc.parallelize([(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)]).toDF()
  counts = df.select([
      count(when(col(c) > 0.1, 1)).alias(c) for c in df.columns
  ])
  ```

  ```
  DataFrame[_1: bigint, _2: bigint, _3: bigint]
  ```
- `collect` the `first` `Row`:

  ```
  a_row = counts.first()
  ```

  ```
  Row(_1=0, _2=1, _3=1)
  ```
- Convert to Python `dict`:

  ```
  a_dict = a_row.asDict()
  ```

  ```
  {'_1': 0, '_2': 1, '_3': 1}
  ```
- And iterate over its items, keeping key, when value is truthy:

  ```
  [c for c, v in a_dict.items() if v]
  ```

  or explicitly checking count:

  ```
  [c for c, v in a_dict.items() if v > 0]
  ```